# android refresh UI of fragment kept ina view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        logger = LogWrapper.getInstance();
        logger.debugLog(TAG+"onCreateView", "On create View Start");
        parentActivity = (CoreWorkFlowActivity) getActivity();
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary_layout, container, false);
        this.inflater = inflater;

        activateSystem = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.activate_system);
        ivretestAll = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.ivretest);
        activateSystem.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivretestAll.setOnClickListener(this);
        explistView = (ExpandableListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.explistview);
        explistView.setGroupIndicator(null);

        hiddenlayout = (RelativeLayout)mView.findViewById(R.id.hiddenLayout);
        buttonlayout = (RelativeLayout)mView.findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
        prepareListData();

        explistAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(parentActivity, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        explistView.setAdapter(explistAdapter);
        explistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return mView;}
```

when i am navigating through a viewpager the fragment's UI is not refreshed .Please give me a solution

Comment: have you tried to refresh the data in `onResume` of the fragment

Comment: yes i am trying to incorporate notifysetdatachanged but app is crashing when i am sliding to the fragment.

Comment: prepareListData();

actually fetches the data from the manager class.

Comment: could you post the locat of the crash?

Comment: public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  //
  //explistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  
  setUserVisibleHint(true);
  
  
 }
 @Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    explistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     
 }
last line it is crashing on notifydatachanged

Comment: logcat of the crash?, and please update your question and format it with the new input